# IE9.js Cannot read property '1' of null / navigator.appVersion.match(...) is null Line 6

Tags: javascript

I've included [Google's IE7/IE8/IE9.js](https://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn-history/r35/trunk/lib/IE9.js) to my website, now I get the following error in Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null IE9.js:6`

Firefox is a bit more detailed: `navigator.appVersion.match(...) is null Line 6`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code around line 6 of IE9.js?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is closed as too localised.

Comment: I agree with you @MattEllen - the answer can be found in the official documentation, but I'm quite sure that more people will make the same mistake I did, and chances are big that they'll find the answer here.

Comment: this question is valid!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in question reads:

```
var q=h.appVersion=navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE (\d\.\d)/)[1]-0
```

Since neither Chrome nor Firefox have "MSIE" in their `appVersion`, the method returns `null`, and then the code tries to get the property called `1` from `null`. Hence the exception.

You could include the script using conditional comments to prevent this error.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script src="IE9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: [As instructed in the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Comment: Ahh I feel so stupid now. I totally forgot about the conditional comment. Thank you! I hope my stupidity helps someone else though.